# New Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

As some of you may have heard on chat, I had to forfeit being a mod here on Anime ([it was great fun while it lasted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lGzc.gif)) because of my new position on Stack Exchange ([huzzah!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/)).

Since we still don't have a prediction for when this site will be fully graduated and able to host its first elections, a replacement for the position I left open was in order.

I am pleased to announce that senshin has stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed, and to continue to help the site grow into a huge success.

[image: senshin]

Please welcome senshin for the hard work and time they contribute.

You can read about the Pro-Tem Moderator program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **there'll be elections once the site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congratulations @senshin (Also to JNat on their new position) :)

Comment: We really still don't have a timeline for graduation? :\

Comment: @senshin [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/208518) is the best timeline we can give you as of now. And it's been like that [for a while now](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697?m=12179914#12179914).

Comment: Congratulations @senshin, is it not going to be tough for you to be mod of two beta sites? Hoping its not.